# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I was exploring caves, on one of the treasure hunt quests, and found a large quantity of what looked like fallen rock, which highlighted when using Witcher Senses.

[image: Example of Symbol]

As shown in the image above, there was a symbol that showed up at the same time. I assumed that I should clear this, using either Aard or a bomb - but neither of these worked.

What does this symbol mean, and/or (vaguely related), how would I clear this rockfall?

Comment: It appears that, after a little more Googling (using the quest instead of odd descriptions of the symbol), that this is something I will acquire later in the quest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering the details would be a minor spoiler, this symbol is explained in an early main quest. You can't clear this before you complete that main quest and receive a particular item.

> During the quest "Wandering in the Dark" you encounter illusions like this and Keira gives you the eye of nehaleni, which allows you to dispel any illusion